# Tensorflow - Converting a pruned model to a lower quantization with tflite

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, quantization, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to quantize a pruned tensorflow model using TFLite. Both the pruning and quantization work independently, but when I try to prune and then quant I get this error: `ValueError: Input 0 of node sequential/prune_low_magnitude_dense/AssignVariableOp was passed float from sequential/prune_low_magnitude_dense/Mul/ReadVariableOp/resource:0 incompatible with expected resource.` and when I try to quant and then prune I get this error: `ValueError: 'prune_low_magnitude' can only prune an object of the following types: tf.keras.models.Sequential, tf.keras functional model, tf.keras.layers.Layer, list of tf.keras.layers.Layer. You passed an object of type: bytes.`

What should I do to make these operations compatible? The model is of type tf.keras.models.Sequential, and for testing purposes is only one layer deep.

Comment: Python 3.6, Tensorflow 2.1, sparsity function comes from tensorflow_model_optimization which is at version 0.2.1. Windows 10 if that matters.

Comment: I am also encountering this issue. Looking for an answer now.

Comment: No answer since 1 year ?

Answer (score 0):

As shown in this example:

https://github.com/tensorflow/model-optimization/blob/master/tensorflow_model_optimization/python/examples/quantization_with_sparsity/keras/mnist_cnn.py

Seems like you should strip_pruning.